# Digitized Qurʾān available online?

Tags: quran

Are there any complete manuscripts of the Qurʾān available online (digitized)?

Thank you.

Comment: For example, something like http://www.aleppocodex.org/ but obviously a Qurʾān instead.

Comment: http://www.islamic-awareness.org/Quran/Text/Mss/

Comment: @Ali, make an answer so you can get the points, even if you're just posting the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link gives pointers to the existence of various manuscripts](http://www.islamic-awareness.org/Quran/Text/Mss/) and [here is the page which *claims* to offer CDROM for Sana manuscripts](http://www.unesco.org/webworld/mdm/visite/sanaa/en/present1.html). I doubt whether the entire corpus of all the  manuscript is availiable online in one place, they may be available at the websites of the [specific museums](http://www.islamic-awareness.org/Quran/Text/Mss/) which hold them.